# Inserting in to MySQL database using AJAX + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to insert data from form to database without refreshing page, my HTML page looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="">Enter Name
            <input type="text" name="t1" id="t1">
            </td>
            <br>Enter City
            <input type="text" name="t2" id="t2">
            </td>
            <br>
            <input type="button" name="button1" value="Insert to DB" onClick="aa()">
        </form>
        <div id="d1"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function aa() {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLhttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "insert.php?name=" + document.getElementById("t1").value + "&city" + document.getElementById("t2").value, false);
                xmlhttp.send(null);

                document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my insert.php looks like:

```
<?php
    $name = $_GET["name"];
    $city = $_GET["city"];

    mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
    mysql_select_db("dwh");
    mysql_query("insert into table1 values('$name','$city')");
    echo "Record inserted";
?>
```

In my opinion this should send PHP all data in "get" and php should just take it and insert it. Somehow it's not. Maybe i  miss something, can you help me to find a problem?

browser console say:

```
(index):16 Uncaught ReferenceError: XMLhttpRequest is not defined(index):16 aa(index):9 onclick
```

Thank you a lot.

p.s. I understand my MYSQL connect is security risk, this was created just to test how to make it work.

Comment: The inclusion of jQuery here seems moot as you don't use it at all.

Comment: Try removing `method="post"`

Comment: Please, _please_, ***stop using the `mysql` extension***, it's ***depreacted***, and has been for some time. [***Read the red warning on the man***](http://php.net/mysql_query), and click the links. Learn to use (and love) `PDO` and/or `mysqli` (the `i` is for _improved_). Those are the replacement extensions

Comment: Fred, remove post didn't help :( ,  Elias yea i will definitly use PDO, this was made just for test (i also need to escape values)

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: add `=` after `&city`

Comment: I don't think the values are accessable at all like this. I think you need to use a submit

Comment: Good point Prerak, unfortunately like that before atleast name should insert, i edited it but still didn't help me with my problem :(

Comment: @user3154108 I think they are, he's using a valid xmlhttprequest or better known as ajax call.

Comment: @Mouser maybe I am getting confused with ajax fileuploads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (index):16 Uncaught ReferenceError: XMLhttpRequest is not defined(index):16 aa(index):9 onclick

JavaScript is case sensitive. The function is `XMLHttpRequest` (with a capital H).

Comment: I'm wondering why on earth did they decide to make it case-sensitive lol it's kind of silly if you think of it. Variables I can understand, but functions?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an equal sign following the word "city" in `&city` and is required when you build the query string:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "insert.php?name=" + document.getElementById("t1").value + "&city" + document.getElementById("t2").value, false);
```

should be

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "insert.php?name=" + document.getElementById("t1").value + "&city=" + document.getElementById("t2").value, false);
```

Comment: Thank you James, this was correct point ( I think already mentioned by Fred ), unfortunately don't fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try include the column names of tables, ex:

```
insert into table1 (column1, column2) values('$name','$city')
```

in addition, use another variable to check if your query execute successfully or not:

```
$result = mysql_query("insert into table1 (column1, column2) values('$name','$city')");
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: the columns are not needed to be specified if you keep their order in values

Comment: That shouldn't really matter. It's good practice, but the data should automatically populate themselves.

Comment: You're welcome Paul. It is good practice though and I for one always use the columns to match. *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that you need to fix:

1. In line `var xmlhttp = new XMLhttpRequest();` it should be `var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();` with a capital `H`.
2. You need to give `id` to `<input>` as you are appending the value by `getElementById()`. Currently there are no elements for the `id` that you have passed.